# Why do go modules fail without detailed information, at pulling certain correct commits which are valid?

Tags: go, module

I have a dependency in an upstream repository in my go.sub file: `github.com/prometheus/common v0.0.0-20190416093430-c873fb1f9420` which clearly exists in the real world: https://github.com/prometheus/common/commit/c873fb1f9420b83ee703b4361c61183b4619f74d.  Is there any reason why go `finding:...` steps which run in my build, would fail on this.

It's clearly a valid SHA... however, When I run my builds, I get the following output:

```
2019-11-05 06:24:37 gobuilds.Compile : 06:24:37.496 calico_all_build INFO         go: finding github.com/prometheus/common v0.0.0-20190416093430-c873fb1f9420
2019-11-05 06:24:41 gobuilds.Compile : 06:24:41.644 calico_all_build INFO         go: error loading module requirements
2019-11-05 06:24:42 gobuilds.Compile : 06:24:42.425 calico_all_build INFO         make[1]: *** [bin/calico-typha-amd64] Error 1
```

The version I'm using is 1.12.8 (edit, typo before).

*UPDATE*

One follow up question I have - is there a way to add fine grained debugging information to the go build calls which lead to the go get `fetching` of repositories?  Ultimately, that is at the crux of the issue Im having.

Comment: Did you `go get` first?

Comment: Your question says you're using 1.10 but the output mentions modules which were introduced in 1.11. Can you clarify?

Comment: Now your question says 1.12 but your comment says 1.13 - but either way you have modules so it makes some sense. Did you `go get` first before building?

Comment: yup, edited the question to the current version (1.12.8) , deleting that comment.

Comment: And, to answer your other question, no - im not `go getting` at all.

Comment: Then that may be your issue - if you haven't downloaded your dependencies, you're not going to be able to build.

Comment: Hmmm, My build is fetching several other repositories... are you sure go get is always required ?

Comment: Interestingly im finding that the ` go: error loading module requirements` happens at a different time during my builds... so im suspecting some kind of http timeout which may occur, and thus am wondering if there is a way to debug the go get command that is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is: that the question is based on a false premise.

That is, I originally assumed that the last statement before my go build failure was the one that failed, but I was wrong.  In fact, if a module is not pullable, you will get explicit error reports for it, for example:

```
go: github.com/golang/glog@v0.0.0-20160126235308-23def4e6c14b: unexpected status (https://***.***@artifacts.domain.com/api/go/go-domain/github.com/golang/glog/@v/23def4e6c14b.mod): 404 Not Found
```

But you might have many more succesfull operations which occur, before the build is failed and reported as failing to satisfy module requirements.
Thus, if you have a module which is fundamentally broken, you might get a completely different build log every time.  This is because the nature of how `go build` triggers the fetching `finding` operations - if (1) Go modules are enabled and (2) the go module you are searching for is *not* in the current GOPATH , then you will see something like this:

```
jayunit100@k8s-vmware:~/mygoapp# go build
go: finding github.com/jayunit100/blah v1.2.3
go: downloading github.com/jayunit100/blah v1.2.3
```

That is, the module is pulled down at build time, however, go build's fetching of repositories is done in a non-deterministic order, as you can see in the following logs (see how the download for `logrus` starts, and several other downloads start during that time, and then half a second later, the extraction of the `logrus` happens later on.

```
2019-11-06 11:46:46 gobuilds.Compile : 11:46:46.438 calico_all_build INFO         go: downloading github.com/projectcalico/logrus v1.0.4-calico
2019-11-06 11:46:46 gobuilds.Compile : 11:46:46.440 calico_all_build INFO         go: downloading github.com/prometheus/client_golang v0.9.1
2019-11-06 11:46:46 gobuilds.Compile : 11:46:46.444 calico_all_build INFO         go: downloading github.com/docopt/docopt-go v0.0.0-20160216232012-784ddc588536
2019-11-06 11:46:46 gobuilds.Compile : 11:46:46.454 calico_all_build INFO         go: downloading k8s.io/client-go v12.0.0+incompatible
2019-11-06 11:46:46 gobuilds.Compile : 11:46:46.477 calico_all_build INFO         go: downloading k8s.io/apimachinery v0.0.0-20190612205821-1799e75a0719
2019-11-06 11:46:46 gobuilds.Compile : 11:46:46.504 calico_all_build INFO         go: downloading github.com/coreos/go-semver v0.3.0
2019-11-06 11:46:46 gobuilds.Compile : 11:46:46.510 calico_all_build INFO         go: extracting github.com/projectcalico/logrus v1.0.4-calico
```

Ultimately in the above question, the failure which occured wasn't actually associated with the repositories in the logging but rather with repositories which were pulled down much earlier in the build stage.

That is, when you see that a go module `fetch` happens followed by a go module `error loading module requirements`, you should look at all the logs before the failure , to find the error message, and never assume that the *last* operation before the error report, is the *actual* operation which failed.

I do not know exactly how long it takes for go build to 'fail' after an error, but, it does appear that certain errors can happen and gomodules will continue attempting to do more work for some period of time do to various other concurrenct finding/fetching operations.

TL;DR, go build has concurrency elements in it, pay attention to that when debugging complex module pulls.

Comment: did you find a way to disable the go build concurrency? I tried doing so with  GOMAXPROCS=1 but that does not appear to help. In the analogous issue I am debugging now, that's exactly the problem, a different build log every time. A go mod tidy (on 1.12) does not help me. But I will take the advice you have for now and review my logs very carefully.